# Write Print Statements into Text File (Python)

Tags: python, text, text-files

I have some code that works when I run the function but I want the print statements to be added into an empty file with the name `nameWhole`. I'm not sure how to do this because the print statements are in a while loop and some of the things I need added to the file are dictionaries (which I know cannot be added into a text file)

```
def errors():
date = sessionStartFMT()
extraPos = findExtraPos()
extraBehavior = findExtraBehavior()
startStops = startStop()
behavior = []
actor = []
subject = []
startBehavior = []
stopBehavior = []

namept1 = date[1]
namept2 = str(namept1[:10])
nameWhole = 'errors_'+ namept2 +'.csv'
file = open(nameWhole, 'w') 

with open('behaviorsTable.csv') as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for row in read:
        actor.append(row[4])
        subject.append(row[5])
        if row[7] != "":
            behavior.append(row[7])
        else:
            behavior.append(row[10])

x = 0
while x < len(startStops):
    if startStops[x] == "Start":
        startBehavior.append(behavior[x])
    elif startStops[x] == 'Stop':
        stopBehavior.append(behavior[x])
    x += 1

if len(startBehavior) != len(stopBehavior):
    startCounter = dict(Counter(startBehavior))
    stopCounter = dict(Counter(stopBehavior))

print(startCounter)
print(stopCounter)
print(extraBehavior + ' is started and never stopped')
print('')

x = 0
count = 0
while x < len(behavior):
    if behavior[x] == extraBehavior:
        print(behavior[x], actor[x], subject[x], startStops[x])
        if count == extraPos:
            print('error occured')
            break
        elif count != extraPos:
            count += 1
            x += 1
    else:
        x += 1
```

Here is the output (and how I need the text file to look):

```
{'Feed Forage': 22, 'Groom': 11, 'Nonsocial Play': 8, 'Social Play': 15}
{'Feed Forage': 21, 'Groom': 11, 'Nonsocial Play': 8, 'Social Play': 15}
Feed Forage is started and never stopped
Feed Forage Nm Nm Start
Feed Forage Nm Nm Stop
Feed Forage Nm Nm Start
Feed Forage Nm Nm Stop
Feed Forage Nm Nm Start
Feed Forage Nm Nm Stop
Feed Forage Nm Nm Start
Feed Forage Nm Nm Stop
Feed Forage Nm Nm Start
Feed Forage Nm Nm Stop
Feed Forage Sv Sv Start
Feed Forage Sv Sv Stop
Feed Forage Sv Sv Start
Error occurred
```

Please let me know if you have some ideas on how to do this!

Comment: Instead of print, you should put everything in a variable, and finally write everything into a file.

Comment: I don't get this sentence "some of the things I need added to the file are dictionaries (which I know cannot be added into a text file)". Why dictionnaries could not be written to a file, it does not make a lot of sense but you can do that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the above question to clarify. thanks

Comment: can you fix your indentation? It's impossible to tell which blocks are supposed to be nested where

Comment: @wpercy the indentation is correct

Comment: @katiedidkatie no, it definitely is not. the code you have there will raise an IndentationError on line 2, I can promise you.